# How to setup .prettierrc with the same default format document config of Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

in my case I need the config Prettier looks like when I do default "Format document" in VSCode. But I can't find the configuration.
Thanks for helping

Comment: By default it is `semi` true, `singleQuote` true, `printWidth` 120.

Comment: thanks, but when I do the formatting there is still some difference

Comment: They also have a property `"editor.insertSpaces": false`, I'm not sure if it has a Prettier equivalent.